# Should I label reflections of objects in a dataset?

Tags: dataset, object-detection, labeling

At first glance, this might seem like an obvious "no", but consider this:  you are trying to train a neural network to recognize humans.  You have a picture with a person, who is visible, and a mirror with a visible reflection of that person.  The model identifies both the person and the reflection as people.  The "person" in the mirror has every feature pertaining to a person and for all intents and purposes is indistinguishable from a person.  Could penalizing the computer for misclassifying the reflection ultimately hurt performance?  Is there any reason *not* to label the reflection as a person other than because it simply isn't?